# load information from file to table

Tags: c

I want to load information from the file to store in a table but I find that there's an error during loading the information and that the function `void charger_Etudiant(Etudiant *E)` does not display the information as they are stored in the file, someone to help me please :)

```
typedef struct Etudiant
{
  char nom[64];
  char prenom[64];

  char CNI[64];
  int sante;
  int niveau_scolaire;
  int  Code_confidentiel;
  int  CNE;
} Etudiant;
```

the function is:

```
 void charger_Etudiant(Etudiant *E)
 {
   int i=0;
   FILE *fichier = NULL;
   fichier = fopen("Info_Etudiant.txt", "r");

   if (fichier != NULL)
   {
       while(i<2&&!feof(fichier))
       {
         fscanf(fichier,"%d\t\t%s %s\t\t%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%d",&E[i].Code_confidentiel,E[i].nom,E[i].prenom,&E[i].CNE,E[i].CNI,&E[i].niveau_scolaire,&E[i].sante);
         printf("%d\t\t%s %s\t\t%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%d",E[i].Code_confidentiel,E[i].nom,E[i].prenom,E[i].CNE,E[i].CNI,E[i].niveau_scolaire,E[i].sante);
         i++;
       }
       fclose(fichier);
   }
 }
```

for exemple the information in the file is written in the following form and I want to store them in a table structure :

123     BADR HARI       10043720        SJ26825     1       3

Comment: (a) Show some sample input. (b) Tell us exactly what problem your experiencing (what error?).

Comment: Is it mandatory to save it in text format?

Comment: the function """void charger_Etudiant(Etudiant *E)""" does not post up the information as they are stored in the file. this is the problem

Comment: iharob yes it's mandatory

Comment: Pleas provide the minimum piece of code we can use to reproduce the issue

Comment: You use `fgets` to get input from the user and then `sscanf` to parse it, why don't you use exactly the same technique for reading the text file?

Comment: this is the minimum piece of code

Comment: It's not, what are you passing to `void remplissage_info_etudient(Etudiant *E)`?

Comment: iharbo give me an exemple please

Comment: `Etudiant E; remplissage_info_etudient(&E);` problem! that would be very much a possible cause of strange behavior, it would compile though. Another thing is the input, the file content.

Comment: iharbo the role of this function void remplissage_info_etudient(Etudiant *E) is filling the information of students and store them in a file

Comment: Check the return value from `fscanf()` to see if it actually parses the number of expected fields. In particular, you are telling `fscanf()` to expect two literal tab characters between the `123` and `BADR` in your sample input, but your sample input appears to have a single space there instead... Similar situations may arise in the following fields - `fscanf()` is quite literal about the non-field-specifier bits of its format string...

Comment: I already delete tab between fields but it's didn't work, also in the file there is a tab betwen fields :)

Comment: @twalberg "you are telling fscanf() to expect two literal tab characters" is incorrect.  Those white-space `char` in the format will match any number of white-space in the file input.  Further, those white-space `char` in the format are not needed as `"%s"` `"%d"` will consume, and not save, any leading white-space.

Comment: @chux Yep. My bad - I was thinking for some reason that only applied to a literal space character, and that the tabs were treated like other non-whitespace literal characters (probably because I'm in the habit of just using a space when I want whitespace consumed, and never considered using any of the other possibilities). However, the bit about checking the return value from `fscanf()` is still highly recommended...

Answer (score 2):

I am not a fan of `scanf()` or of `fscanf()`. I prefer to use `fgets()` and `strtok()` and `sscanf()` to extract the fields, although here `atoi()` is good enough. One advantage of `strtok()` is that if the field delimitors change, there is only one tweak required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRLENG     63

typedef struct Etudiant {
  char nom [STRLENG+1];
  char prenom [STRLENG+1];
  char CNI [STRLENG+1];
  int sante;
  int niveau_scolaire;
  int Code_confidentiel;
  int CNE;
} Etudiant;

int charger_Etudiant(Etudiant *E) {
    int i=0;
    char buff[512];
    char *tok;
    char delims[] = "\t\n";
    FILE *fichier = NULL;
    fichier = fopen("Info_Etudiant.txt", "r");
    if (fichier != NULL) {
        while(fgets (buff, 512, fichier) != NULL) {
            memset(&E[i], 0, sizeof(Etudiant));
            if (tok = strtok (buff, delims)) {
                E[i].Code_confidentiel = atoi(tok);
                if (tok = strtok (NULL, delims)) {
                    strncpy (E[i].nom, tok, STRLENG);
                    if (tok = strtok (NULL, delims)) {
                        strncpy (E[i].prenom, tok, STRLENG);
                        if (tok = strtok (NULL, delims)) {
                            E[i].CNE = atoi(tok);
                            if (tok = strtok (NULL, delims)) {
                                strncpy (E[i].CNI, tok, STRLENG);
                                if (tok = strtok (NULL, delims)) {
                                    E[i].niveau_scolaire = atoi(tok);
                                    if (tok = strtok (NULL, delims)) {
                                        E[i].sante = atoi(tok);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            printf("%d\t\t%s %s\t\t%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\n",
                    E[i].Code_confidentiel, E[i].nom, E[i].prenom,
                    E[i].CNE, E[i].CNI,E[i].niveau_scolaire,E[i].sante);
            i++;
            }
        }
        fclose(fichier);
    }
    return i;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use `feof()` to detect EOF condition.  Check the return value from input functions instead.
2. Like [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27659682/2410359) suggest using `fgets()`

.

```
#define MAXINTLEN (20)
// Use 2x size line buffer   
#define MAXLINELEN ((sizeof(Etudiant) + 4*MAXINTLEN) * 2) 

char buffer[MAXLINELEN + 2];

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fichier) != NULL) {
  int cnt = sscanf(buffer,"%d%63s%63s%d%63s%d%d", 
      &E[i].Code_confidentiel, E[i].nom, E[i].prenom, &E[i].CNE, 
      E[i].CNI, &E[i].niveau_scolaire, &E[i].sante);
  if (cnt != 7) {
    break;  // scan error
  } 
  printf("%d\t\t%s %s\t\t%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%d",
      E[i].Code_confidentiel, E[i].nom, E[i].prenom, E[i].CNE,
      E[i].CNI, E[i].niveau_scolaire, E[i].sante);
  i++;
}
```

When scanning the `"\t\t"` does not necessarily scan 2 tabs.  Any white space in `scanf()` (except in `%[]`) scans any number of white spaces.  Code could use `sscanf(buffer,"%d %63s %63s %d %63s %d %d", ...` for clarity, but it does the same thing.

Specifiers `"%d"` and `"%s"` consume leading white-space anyways.

Always limit string inputs.  Example: `%63s`